# Why is there sometimes a は used in conjugated, negative, formal i-adjectives?

Tags: particle-は, adjectives, negation, i-adjectives

A few times now, I have seen a negative i-adjective with a は　in between the く and the ありません. I have seen it usually present when it is a response to a question. Like the example below.

いいえ、車は赤くはありません。

Translations of it are no different than '車は赤くありません。,' however, so I am not sure what the addition of the は adds, or what circumstances it should be used, or if it's even correct.

Can anyone shed some light on when/how/if は is used with the negative i-adjectives? Appreciate any help!

Comment: It just adds emphasis.

Comment: Thanks!  Would it be usually preferred in every day conversation, would you say?

Comment: I don't hear it often. Except maybe when someone is rejecting an accusation of some sort (doesn't have to be serious, can be used even while joking). "You like pizza, right? No I do NOT like it!" This kind of thing.

Comment: Ah, okay. That does make sense, thinking of some of the places I've seen it. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd suggest 'topicalisation' as a better word than the (unpleasantly vague) 'emphasis'. See the question linked to by naruto.